# Google MAPS API V3 with icon types and select function

Tags: javascript, xml, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am in the process of migrating my Google API v2 maps to version 3.

I have partially completed this successfully - see below

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-    strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
<head> 
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" /> 
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
<title>Google Maps Javascript API v3 Example: Loading the data from an XML</title> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="downloadxml.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
html, body { height: 100%; } 
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
//<![CDATA[
  // this variable will collect the html which will eventually be placed in the select 
  var select_html = ""; 

  // arrays to hold copies of the markers
  // because the function closure trick doesnt work there 
  var gmarkers = []; 

 // global "map" variable
  var map = null;




var image = {
url: 'ghd.png',
// This marker is 20 pixels wide by 32 pixels tall.
size: new google.maps.Size(59, 70),
// The origin for this image is 0,0.
origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
// The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at 0,32.
anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 70)
};
var shadow = {
url: 'images/beachflag_shadow.png',
// The shadow image is larger in the horizontal dimension
// while the position and offset are the same as for the main image.
size: new google.maps.Size(37, 32),
origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 32)
};
// Shapes define the clickable region of the icon.
// The type defines an HTML &lt;area&gt; element 'poly' which
// traces out a polygon as a series of X,Y points. The final
// coordinate closes the poly by connecting to the first
// coordinate.
var shape = {
  coord: [1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18 , 1],
  type: 'poly'
};



// A function to create the marker and set up the event window function 
function createMarker(latlng, name, html) {
var contentString = html;
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    map: map,
     shadow: shadow,
    icon: image,
    zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
    });

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });

    // ======= Add the entry to the select box =====
    select_html += '<option> ' + name + '<\/option>';
    // ==========================================================
// save the info we need to use later
gmarkers.push(marker);
return marker;
}

  // ======= This function handles selections from the select box ====
  // === If the dummy entry is selected, the info window is closed ==
  function handleSelected(opt) {
    var i = opt.selectedIndex - 1; 
    if (i > -1) {
      google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i],"click");
    }
    else {
      infowindow.close();
    }
  }

function initialize() {
// create the map
var myOptions = {
zoom: 2,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(32.8624,-96.654218),
mapTypeControl: true,
mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
navigationControl: true,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
                            myOptions);

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.close();
    });

  // Read the data from 100.xml
  downloadUrl("MW_100.xml", function(doc) {
    var xmlDoc = xmlParse(doc);
    var markers = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");

    // ==== first part of the select box ===
    select_html = '<select onChange="handleSelected(this)">' +
                    '<option selected> - Select a location - <\/option>';
    // =====================================

    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      // obtain the attribues of each marker
      var lat = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat"));
      var lng = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"));
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
      var html = markers[i].getAttribute("html");
      var label = markers[i].getAttribute("label");

      // create the marker
      var marker = createMarker(point,label,html);
    }
    // ===== final part of the select box =====
    select_html += '<\/select>';
    document.getElementById("selection").innerHTML = select_html;
  });}

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
{ size: new google.maps.Size(150,50)});


// This Javascript is based on code provided by the
// Community Church Javascript Team
// http://www.bisphamchurch.org.uk/   
// http://econym.org.uk/gmap/
// from the v2 tutorial page at:
// http://econym.org.uk/gmap/basic3.htm 
//]]>
</script> 

</head> 
<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" onload="initialize()"> 

<!-- you can use tables or divs for the overall layout --> 
       <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 700px; height: 450px"></div> 
<!-- ====== this div will hold the select box ==== -->
<div id="selection"></div>
<!-- ============================================= -->

<noscript><p><b>JavaScript must be enabled in order for you to use Google Maps.</b> 
  However, it seems JavaScript is either disabled or not supported by your browser. 
  To view Google Maps, enable JavaScript by changing your browser options, and then 
  try again.</p>
</noscript> 

</body> 
</html>
```

How ever, I want to introduce different types for the icon, and have this sub categorisation of icontypes as a field within the xml data. So I tried adjusting code to following, but does not output. Html/js below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtm
/DTD/xhtml1-    strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
<head> 
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" /> 
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
<title>Google Maps Javascript API v3 Example: Loading the data from an XML</title> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="downloadxml.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
html, body { height: 100%; } 
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
//<![CDATA[
  // this variable will collect the html which will eventually be placed in the select 
  var select_html = ""; 

  // arrays to hold copies of the markers
  // because the function closure trick doesnt work there 
  var gmarkers = []; 

   var gicons = [];

    var icon = new GIcon();
icon.iconSize = new GSize(46, 44);
  icon.iconAnchor = new GPoint(23, 44);
  icon.infoWindowAnchor = new GPoint(23, 7);

  icon.shadowSize = new GSize(22, 20);
  icon.shadowAnchor = new GPoint(100, 60);



  gicons["yellow"] = new GIcon(icon, "ghd_grey.png");
   gicons["grey"] = new GIcon(icon, "ghd2.png");


 // global "map" variable
  var map = null;
// A function to create the marker and set up the event window function 
function createMarker(latlng, name, html, icontype) {
var contentString = html;
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    map: map,
    gicons:icontype,
    zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
    });

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });

    // ======= Add the entry to the select box =====
    select_html += '<option> ' + name + '<\/option>';
    // ==========================================================
// save the info we need to use later
gmarkers.push(marker);
return marker;
}

  // ======= This function handles selections from the select box ====
  // === If the dummy entry is selected, the info window is closed ==
  function handleSelected(opt) {
    var i = opt.selectedIndex - 1; 
    if (i > -1) {
      google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i],"click");
    }
    else {
      infowindow.close();
    }
  }

function initialize() {
// create the map
var myOptions = {
zoom: 8,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.907787,-79.359741),
mapTypeControl: true,
mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
navigationControl: true,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
                            myOptions);

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.close();
    });

  // Read the data from 100.xml
  downloadUrl("MW_100.xml", function(doc) {
    var xmlDoc = xmlParse(doc);
    var markers = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");

    // ==== first part of the select box ===
    select_html = '<select onChange="handleSelected(this)">' +
                    '<option selected> - Select a location - <\/option>';
    // =====================================

    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      // obtain the attribues of each marker
      var lat = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat"));
      var lng = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"));
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
      var html = markers[i].getAttribute("html");
      var label = markers[i].getAttribute("label");
  var icontype = markers[i].getAttribute("icontype");
      // create the marker
      var marker = createMarker(point,label,html,icontype);
    }
    // ===== final part of the select box =====
    select_html += '<\/select>';
    document.getElementById("selection").innerHTML = select_html;
  });
}

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
{ 
size: new google.maps.Size(150,50)
});


// This Javascript is based on code provided by the
// Community Church Javascript Team
// http://www.bisphamchurch.org.uk/   
// http://econym.org.uk/gmap/
// from the v2 tutorial page at:
// http://econym.org.uk/gmap/basic3.htm 
//]]>
</script> 

</head> 
<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" onload="initialize()"> 

<!-- you can use tables or divs for the overall layout --> 
       <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 550px; height: 450px"></div> 
<!-- ====== this div will hold the select box ==== -->
<div id="selection"></div>
<!-- ============================================= -->

<noscript><p><b>JavaScript must be enabled in order for you to use Google Maps.</b> 
  However, it seems JavaScript is either disabled or not supported by your browser. 
  To view Google Maps, enable JavaScript by changing your browser options, and then 
  try again.</p>
</noscript> 


</body> 
</html>
```

Sample xml:
    
    
    
    label="Marker 2" icontype="yellow" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need

```js
var gicons=[];
gicons['yellow'] ="ghd_grey.png";
gicons["grey"] = "ghd2.png";
...
```

and in `createMarker` :

```js
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    map: map,
    icon : gicons[icontype],
    ...
    optimized: false, //important, else zIndex might not work
    zIndex : 10 //google.maps.Marker.MAX_ZINDEX downto 0. 
                //use marker.setZIndex() to set it dynamically
    ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks, works nicely. My final question is I want to stack my markers and bring some to the front. I have tried the following, added field to xml but seems to have no effect on stacking order. I added:   var zIndex =""; function createMarker(latlng, name, html, icontype, zIndex) {
    var contentString = html;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
  icon : gicons[icontype],
   shadow: shadow,
   optimized: false,
        zIndex: 10 
        });

Comment: Yes! zIndex do the trick. I use it myself to show data from a range of years, with the newest on top. The code you show above seems OK. `optimized: false` _must be set on all markers_, else zIndex-order might be broken.